# I have import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; in my code and it works on eclipse but not in command line

Tags: java

I'm using an Apache package; I've add it's jar file location to the classpath environment variable. When I try to compile the code via the command line I get numerous errors including:  package org.apache.commons.io does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the jar that contains this package (in your case apache-commons.jar) on your classpath.

Try to export the packaged jar file with the dependend jars included. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Complile like this:

```
javac -cp .:common-io-xx.jar YourProgram.java
```

Run it like this:

```
java -cp .:common-io-xx.jar YourProgram
```

Comment: thank you for your response ...it compiles good but when I try to execute it with two command line arguments I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyReadFile

Comment: I assume your file is called MyReadFile, right? So it can't find your main class. The period before the colon is what donates the current directory. Did you include the period and are you running the program from the directory where main class, MyReadFile is located?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above option will not work sometimes.

At run time it might not find the class YourProgram :( Strange but true!

In that case just drop common-io-xx.jar under your 
...\Java\jdk1\jre\lib\ext

Ofcourse that will work :)
Only wasted a few hours to get to that conclusion!

Comment: replace jdk1 with your jdk/sdk version